# Asking for multiple user inputs then printing them below separetely

Tags: java, input

I'm trying to make a script that asks for multiple inputs then prints them out below.

For example:

- How many inputs do you want? -> 3
- What is the 1. input? -> 5
- What is the 2. input? -> 3
- What is the 3. input? -> 4

You gave these inputs:

1) 5
2) 3
3) 4

Below you can see how far I got with it. Asks for all the inputs nicely but I can't figure out how to print them out below the input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Inputs {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many inputs?");
        int inp=read.nextInt();


        for (int i=1;i<=inp;i++){
            System.out.print("What was " + i + ". input? ");
            int print=read.nextInt();
            System.out.println(print);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Fran Montero   Can't believe I forgot to ask.. I edited it in below the example.

Comment: You need to store the inputs somewhere to print it later. Smells like a homework to me.

Comment: Create an array of size - number of inputs (`inp`). Save values coming from `read.nextInt()` to that array elements and print them back once all inputs are collected(until your `for` loop exits). After that look at this http://www.ericleschinski.com/c/fizzbuzz_with_java/

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Inputs {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many inputs?");
    int inp=read.nextInt();
    int[] answers = new int[inp];

    for (int i=1;i<=inp;i++){
        System.out.print("What was " + i + ". input? ");
        int print=read.nextInt();
        System.out.println(print);

        answers[i] = print;
    }
    int index = 0;
    for(int a : answers){
        System.out.println( index + ")" + " " + a);
        index ++;
    }
 }
}
```

---

You can code clean it yourself as a practice =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Collections (i used List) to protect your inputs;

```
public class Inputs {
   public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many inputs?");
    int inp=read.nextInt();

    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=1;i<=inp;i++){
        System.out.print("What was " + i + ". input? ");
        int print=read.nextInt();
        numbers.add(print);
        System.out.println(print);
    }
    System.out.println("Inputs are :");
    for (Integer integer : numbers) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
 }
}
```

And the output is;

```
How many inputs?
3
What was 1. input? 5
5
What was 2. input? 3
3
What was 3. input? 4
4
Inputs are :
5
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of integers for later use.

```
int array = new int[inp];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the inputs and print them later

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Inputs {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many inputs?");
    int inp=read.nextInt();
    int[] keepInputsHere=new int[inp];


    for (int i=0;i<inp;i++){
        System.out.print("What was " + i + ". input? ");
        int readInt=read.nextInt();
        keepInputsHere[i]=readInt;
    }
     System.out.print("Print results: ");
     for (int i=0;i<inp;i++){
        System.out.print( keepInputsHere[i]);         
     }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to close the Scanner and separate the login into different functions:

```
public class Inputs {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("How many inputs?");
            int inp = read.nextInt();
            Print(ReadInput(inp,read));
        }

        private static int[] ReadInput(int questionsNo, Scanner sc) {
            int[] inputs = new int[questionsNo];

            for (int i = 0; i < questionsNo; i++) {
                System.out.print("What was " + i + ". input? ");
                int readInt = sc.nextInt();
                inputs[i] = readInt;
            }
            sc.close();
            return inputs;
        }

        private static void Print(int[] inputs) {
            System.out.println("Print results: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                System.out.println( i + ")" + " " + inputs[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```